# c# Delegate and Dispatcher problem

Tags: c#

i get this error when trying this:

> ERROR method name expected.

How should i do to correct the problem

```
delegate void DelegateFillList(DeliveryDoc[] deliveryDocs);
private void FillListViewAssignment(DeliveryDoc[] docs) {
    if(lvMyAssignments.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) {
        lvMyAssignments.ItemsSource = docs;
        lvAllOngoingAssignments.ItemsSource = docs;

        if(m_tempDeliveryDocs != null) {
            txtblockHandOverCount.Text = m_tempDeliveryDocs.Length.ToString();
        }

    } else {
        lvMyAssignments.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            new DelegateFillList(FillListViewAssignment(docs)), null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
new DelegateFillList(FillListViewAssignment(docs)
```

You can't create a delegate that way. You need to provide a *method group* which is just the name of the method:

```
 lvMyAssignments.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
     (new DelegateFillList(FillListViewAssignment), new object[]{docs});
```

Alternatively, you could do it in two statements:

```
DelegateFillList fillList = FillListViewAssignment;
lvMyAssignments.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(fillList, new object[]{docs});
```

The reason for the extra "wrapping" array is that you've only got one argument, which is an array - you don't want it to try to interpret that as a bunch of different arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Change the last line to:

```
 lvMyAssignments.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      new DelegateFillList(FillListViewAssignment), docs);
```

Comment: After i changed. i got this error
Parameter count mismatch:
the FillListViewAssignment needs a parameter docs how to i send it to.

Comment: @Tan: See my (revised) answer for a fix to that problem. I wasn't sure what would be required.

Answer (score 1):

I dun think you have to specify the arguments in the else part..

Try this :

```
lvMyAssignments.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new DelegateFillList(FillListViewAssignment), new object[]{docs});
```

EDITED - Included `new object[]{docs}`. Thanks to Jon and Henk

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
lvMyAssignments.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    new DelegateFillList(FillListViewAssignment(docs)), null);
```

Notice that you pass a method call to the delegate, not the method name. Change it to read:

```
lvMyAssignments.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    new DelegateFillList(FillListViewAssignment),  null);
                                               ^
                                               |
                                               +- removed (docs)
```

Comment: but where should i put the paramter docs. the FillListViewAssignment needs the parameter.